# Firebase: href relative links fail

Tags: css, firebase, firebase-hosting

Is it just me, or with Firebase Hosting, do your relative `href` links fail for files placed in a subdirectory?  For example I have a Folder structure like below but `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` in the highlighted `index.html` file resolves to the root of my site.  The style.css file is there, it's just not shown.

The issue is if I hardcode the URL, if/when I migrate this to a new hosting provider, I'll have to change all that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using rewrites in `firebase.json` to make all pages resolve to `index.html` (or did you say "Y" to the Single-Page App question in `firebase init`)? If so, you will need to do one of two things:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/commas/style.css">

<!-- or -->

<base href="/commas">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Note that if you do `<base>` then **all** relative URLs on your page will be made relative to the specified URL. I'd recommend the first approach.

Comment: I've found that the equivalent of `<base href="./commas/">` is necessary. This is with `{cleanUrls: true, trailingSlash: false}`